# How to be able to get login credentials the docusign api from my app?

Tags: oauth, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate api of docusign that I got from code-examples-java, inside my app.
I created a button inside my web app that redirects to localhost:8080/code-examples-java, but when it opens it needs to write the email and password for docusign.
My web app has login system, so I want to be able to connect in docusign in the moment that i login in my web app without needing again the login credentials in docusign api.

I am looking for a way to send for example a document for signing without needing to login first, because it will be logged in also in docusign when i login in my webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Better than JWT (because there is less setup and consent is much easier) is for your users to:

- Login with your app's authorization system
- one time: authenticate with DocuSign vie authorization code grant flow
- Securely save the refresh token for your user and use it to generate access tokens as needed

Note use the **extended** scope so the refreshed refresh tokens will last.

Note each refresh token must be used within 30 days or it expires

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use JWT instead of Auth Code Grant.

JWT option included in the code-examples-java repo, so just choose that.

That option allows you to avoid the need to login with a user/password.